# Ruby: two ways using try in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to extract a value by using `try` in Ruby.

I found there are two ways of doing this and was playing around with it in irb.

```
>> hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
>> hash.try(:a)
=> nil
>> hash.try(:[], :a)
=> 1
```

I have two questions,

1. What is the difference between `hash.try(:[], :a)` and `hash.try(:a)`? I searched around and found people use both ways.
2. I saw a lot of places using hash.try(:a) to retrieve values, but why my trial returns nil?

Comment: Where did you see `hash.try(:a)`? It doesn't make much sense if `hash` is indeed a hash. Could it have been `hash.dig(:a)`?

Comment: @EricDuminil `hash.try(:a)` is what I typed in irb console to see if I can get value from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash.try(:[], :a)
# 1
```

Tries to invoke the public method `[]` on `hash` passing as `:a` as argument to `[]`. As `:a` is an existing key in the hash, it returns its value.

```
hash.try(:a)
# nil
```

Tries to invoke the public method `:a` on `hash`. As `hash` as the receiver doesn't respond to `:a` then it returns `nil`.

As a clarification, the arguments for `try` are as first the method to be invoked on the receiver, and all the other arguments are the arguments for the method being invoked.

---

If your hash could respond to the method `:a`, `hash.try(:a)` would return the value of that method being called on `hash`:

```
# Just for example purposes
class Hash; def a; :a_monkey_patched_value_for_a; end

hash.try(:a)
# :a_monkey_patched_value_for_a
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear response. Just to clarify if I understand correctly - 
`try` views the first passed argument as a `method`, and the second, third and following arguments as the input params for the `first param`?

Comment: Yes, that's it. _Arguments and blocks are forwarded to the method if invoked_.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me understand a lot!